# Convergence of a sequence and some of its subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following sequences $(a_n)$, $(b_n)=(a_{2n})$, and $(c_n) = (a_{2n-1})$.

I have to show that:

1. if $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ both convergence to $a$, then $(a_n)$ also converges to $a$;
2. if $(a_n)$ converges then $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ also converge;
3. there exist $(a_n)$ not converging but with $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ converging.

I am not sure how to solve this since I only know that $(b_n)$ > $(c_n)$ > $(a_n)$ on the terms how the sequences are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose $(b_n)$  and $(c_n)$ converge to $a$.

Principle:
$(a_n)$ converge to $a$ iff for all subsequences $(n_i)$ of $\mathbb{N}$, $(a_{n_i})$ converge to the same limit $a$.
Proof:
Let a subsequence $(n_i)$ of integers. This subsequence is composed of terms of odd rangs which converge to a and of terms of even rangs which converge also to a, so, the subsequence $(a_{n_i})$ converge to $a$.

A sequence where $(a_n)$ is not converging but $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ are:

For example $a_n=(-1)^n$  is not converging. But $b_n=a_{2n} =1$  so $b_n$ converge to $1$.

$c_n=a_{2n-1} = (-1)^{2n-1} = -1$ and $(c_n)$ converge to $-1$.

remark: a sequence $(a_n)$ is not converging when it have two or more adherence values. this is the case of $(-1)^n$.

If, as Did say, we apply the definition of a convergence sequence:

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_0 \forall n > n_0 : |a_n-l| \le \epsilon$

we apply it to (b_n) and (c_n):

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_b , n_c \forall n > \max(n_b, n_c) : |b_n-a| \le \epsilon, |c_n -a| \le \epsilon$ so

$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists n_0=max(n_b, n_c) \forall n > n_0 : |a_n-a|\le \epsilon$ : $(an) \to a$.

Comment: The "principle" above is true but not the definition of convergence of a sequence, actually the exercise should probably be viewed as a first step towards reaching this principle. As such, this solution is correct but neither the most direct way to solve the exercise nor what was probably expected by those proposing it to user @Maximilian.